# How to find the length of an input

Tags: c, while-loop

i am trying to measure how many numbers my input has.
if i input the following line: `1 2 65 3 4 7`,
i want the output to be `8`.but what I'm getting is 1 2 3 4.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int data;
    int i = 1;   
    while (i <= sizeof(data)) {
        scanf("%d", &data)
        printf("%d", i);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(data)` is evaluated at *compile time* to the size of the `int` type. It has nothing to do with how many numbers your input line has.

Comment: You must have some trigger point to end your input and then you can count them and show the count.

Comment: `sizeof(data)` is constant the size of the type of data (int) maybe 4. So your loop will run 4 times, no matter what you type as input.

Comment: Why should `1 2 65 3 4 7` give the output 8 ?

Answer (score 3):

You are printing `i` which have no relation to the input at all. So no matter what your input is, you'll get `1234`

`sizeof(data)` is the same as `sizeof(int)`, i.e. a constant with value 4 on your system.

If you want to count the number of numbers and don't care about the value of the individual number, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) {
    char s[1024];
    char* p;
    int i = 0;   
    fgets(s, 1024, stdin);
    p=s;

    while (*p != '\0')
    {
        if (!isdigit(*p))
        {
            p++;
        }
        else
        {
            i++;  // Found new number

            // Search for a delimiter, i.e. skip all digits
            p++;
            while (*p != '\0' && isdigit(*p))
            {
                p++;
            }
        }   
    }

    printf("We found %d numbers", i);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
We found 6 numbers
```

Notice that this code will accept any non-digit input as delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

put the scanf before the while-loop and move the printf after the while-loop.

Answer (score -1):

I'm also providing solution according to my openion.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int data = 1;
    int i = 0;   
    // here data != 0 is trigger point for end input,
    // once you done with your inputs you need to last add 0 to terminate
    while (data != 0) {
        scanf("%d", &data)
        printf("Collected Data: %d", data);
        i++;
    }
    printf("Total number of inputs are %d.", i);
}
```

Hope this solution helps you.

Comment: This is not what the OP was asking. He just wants to enter some numbers separated by space on one line and count the number of numbers entered.

Comment: SO is not a Tutorial Site.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    int data[100]; // creating an array

    while(1) { // the loop will run forever
        scanf("%d", &data[i]);

        if (data[i] == -1) { //unless data[i] = -1
            break; // exit while-loop
        }

        i++;
    }

    printf("%d\n", data[2]); // print 2nd integer in data[]

    return 0;
}
```

Do not forget to hit enter once you entered an int. Output of the program:

```
2
56
894
34
6
12
-1

894
```

Hope that helps. :)

Comment: SO is not a Tutorial Site.